# How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object

Tags: c#, generics, list, sorting

I have a class called `Order` which has properties such as `OrderId`, `OrderDate`, `Quantity`, and `Total`. I have a list of this `Order` class:

```cs
List<Order> objListOrder = new List<Order>();
GetOrderList(objListOrder); // fill list of orders
```

I want to sort the list based on one property of the `Order` object; for example, either by `OrderDate` or `OrderID`.

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 2291, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use Linq:

```
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();
```

Comment: how can I sort this in descending order.

Comment: @BonusKun List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder. **OrderByDescending** (o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();

Comment: note that this creates a whole new list with all the items in memory, which *may* be problematic in terms of performance.

Comment: @staafl will `listWithObjects = listWithObjects.OrderByDescending(o => o.Status).ToList();` suffice for such an endeavor?

Comment: @staafl We are ordering a list of object references, not duplicating the objects themselves as far as I'm aware. While this does double the memory used by the list of references it's not as bad as actually duplicating all of the objects themselves so in most scenarios outside of those where we are dealing with huge data sets and holding them in memory is already an issue, then it should suffice.

Comment: This method is slower than the answer below that uses List.Sort(delegate). List.Sort is NLogN, Linq OrderBy somehow is not NLogN

Comment: @staafl, you make a good point.  By default the linq is trying to follow the principle of immutability so you don't end up with concurrency issues.  But the down side is that you end up eating more memory like you are realizing.   That's good you are already aware of that!   So yes, the alternative offered by Ankush to not duplicate is slower as uowad01 points out but you have to choose if you want to focus on performance or stability principles.

Comment: Can I Sort by Order date and then a second property say Name ?

Comment: could i use this without the lambda part?

Answer (score 1154):

If you need to sort the list in-place then you can use the [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) method, passing a [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1) delegate:

```
objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => x.OrderDate.CompareTo(y.OrderDate));
```

If you prefer to create a new, sorted sequence rather than sort in-place then you can use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) method, as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: If your date fields are of type *Nullable* DateTime (i.e. DateTime?), and you get a compile error like "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<...>' because it is not a delegate type", the *real* problem may be that there's no CompareTo method on nullable type DateTime?.  If you're sure the object won't be null, you can cast it to plain DateTime to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the "correct" answer and should be much more efficient than creating a new IEnumerable and then converting it to a new list.

Comment: Of course, if you need descending sort, swap `x` and `y` on the right-hand side of the arrow `=>`.

Comment: The real answer that actually sorts the list in-place

Comment: @PimBrouwers This is the better option period. Even if the amount of memory you are using is not an issue, this solution avoids unnecessary memory allocation which is EXTREMELY expensive. This option is just as simple codewise and an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @JonSchneider For `Nullable<>` (take `DateTime?` as the example) you can use `.Sort((x, y) => Nullable.Compare(x.OrderDate, y.OrderDate))` which will treat null as preceding all non-null values. It is exactly the same as `.Sort((x, y) => Comparer<DateTime?>.Default.Compare(x.OrderDate, y.OrderDate)`.

Comment: Insanely nit-picky, but using a,b instead of x,y is more common for sorting.

Comment: Unless you're calling .ToList() or .ToArray(), using .OrderBy() and .ThenBy() (for the 2nd field) do NOT create a new list, just an iterator.  They are actually MORE efficient than Sort when you don't want to create a new list.

Comment: `result.Sort((x, y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal));` It's ok for me, if you compare string fields. Good luck.

Comment: Note that, according to the docs, this method is _unstable_, whereas `OrderBy` is _stable_. Also, for Lists `Sort` an instance method, while for Arrays it's static. All of this is unnecessarily confusing syntax-wise, I might add.

Comment: Only Shyju has to decide what's the correct answer for his purpose. If he works with different threads and a "global" list the in-place sort could cause funny problems.

Answer (score 245):

To do this without LINQ on .Net2.0:

```
List<Order> objListOrder = GetOrderList();
objListOrder.Sort(
    delegate(Order p1, Order p2)
    {
        return p1.OrderDate.CompareTo(p2.OrderDate);
    }
);
```

If you're on .Net3.0, then LukeH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object/3309292#3309292) is what you're after.

To sort on multiple properties, you can still do it within a delegate. For example:

```
orderList.Sort(
    delegate(Order p1, Order p2)
    {
        int compareDate = p1.Date.CompareTo(p2.Date);
        if (compareDate == 0)
        {
            return p2.OrderID.CompareTo(p1.OrderID);
        }
        return compareDate;
    }
);
```

This would give you **ascending** dates with **descending** orderIds.

However, I wouldn't recommend sticking delegates as it will mean lots of places without code re-use. You should implement an `IComparer` and just pass that through to your `Sort` method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx).

```
public class MyOrderingClass : IComparer<Order>
{
    public int Compare(Order x, Order y)
    {
        int compareDate = x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date);
        if (compareDate == 0)
        {
            return x.OrderID.CompareTo(y.OrderID);
        }
        return compareDate;
    }
}
```

And then to use this IComparer class, just instantiate it and pass it to your Sort method:

```
IComparer<Order> comparer = new MyOrderingClass();
orderList.Sort(comparer);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and should be the correct one as it protects re-initializing the original list (which the LINQ version will always do) providing better encapsulation.

Comment: @wonton, no. The idea is to be able to have different `IComparer` implementations, giving us polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 141):

Simplest way to order a list is to use `OrderBy`

```
 List<Order> objListOrder = 
    source.OrderBy(order => order.OrderDate).ToList();
```

If you want to order by multiple columns like following SQL Query.

```
ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderId
```

To achieve this you can use `ThenBy` like following.

```
  List<Order> objListOrder = 
    source.OrderBy(order => order.OrderDate).ThenBy(order => order.OrderId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 39):

Doing it without Linq as you said:

```
public class Order : IComparable
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Order orderToCompare = obj as Order;
        if (orderToCompare.OrderDate < OrderDate || orderToCompare.OrderId < OrderId)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (orderToCompare.OrderDate > OrderDate || orderToCompare.OrderId > OrderId)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // The orders are equivalent.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then just call .sort() on your list of Orders

Comment: One must first test for `null` on the `as` cast. Which is the whole point of `as`, as (ha, ha) `(Order)obj` throws an exception when it fails. `if(orderToCompare == null) return 1;`.

Comment: +1 for using the interface, which makes the code easier to maintain and  clearly exposes the object's capabilities.

Comment: If Bill and Ted ever show up I'll ask them to take me back to Oct 16, 2014 so I can correct my mistake above - `as` returns `null` if the cast fails. But at least the null-test is right.

Comment: @radarbob yeah.. oops. :) But! This function is intended to be used automatically by a sort over a list that is `List<Order>` so the type should be guaranteed to match on the `as` so 2014 you probably didn't write a bug, so much as avoiding an unnecessary guard statement :)

Comment: *should be guaranteed*  Interesting point. If it is well encapsulated such that it cannot be called except to pass a `List<Order>`; but you and I both have met the self-encapsulated programmer who's unspoken presumption is "i'm writing this code so it won't be used wrong"

Answer (score 34):

**A Classical Object Oriented Solution**

First I must genuflect to the awesomeness of LINQ....  Now that we've got that out of the way

A variation on JimmyHoffa answer. With generics the `CompareTo` parameter becomes type safe.

```
public class Order : IComparable<Order> {

    public int CompareTo( Order that ) {
        if ( that == null ) return 1;
        if ( this.OrderDate > that.OrderDate) return 1;
        if ( this.OrderDate < that.OrderDate) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

// in the client code
// assume myOrders is a populated List<Order>
myOrders.Sort();
```

This default sortability is re-usable of course. That is each client does not have to redundantly re-write the sorting logic. Swapping the "1" and "-1" (or the logic operators, your choice) reverses the sort order.

Comment: Simple approach for sorting objects in a List. But I do not understand why you return 1 if (that == null)?

Comment: it means `this` object is greater than null.  For the purposes of sorting,  a null object reference "is less than" `this` object. That's just the way I decided to define how nulls will sort.

Answer (score 21):

// Totally generic sorting for use with a gridview

```
public List<T> Sort_List<T>(string sortDirection, string sortExpression, List<T> data)
    {

        List<T> data_sorted = new List<T>();

        if (sortDirection == "Ascending")
        {
            data_sorted = (from n in data
                              orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, sortExpression) ascending
                              select n).ToList();
        }
        else if (sortDirection == "Descending")
        {
            data_sorted = (from n in data
                              orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, sortExpression) descending
                              select n).ToList();

        }

        return data_sorted;

    }

    public object GetDynamicSortProperty(object item, string propName)
    {
        //Use reflection to get order type
        return item.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item, null);
    }
```

Comment: Or, you know, `data.OrderBy()`. Bit easier that re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: The idea is this will work with any type of object. Where as OrderBy() only works with strongly typed objects.

Answer (score 13):

Using LINQ

```
objListOrder = GetOrderList()
                   .OrderBy(o => o.OrderDate)
                   .ToList();

objListOrder = GetOrderList()
                   .OrderBy(o => o.OrderId)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a generic LINQ extension method that does not create an extra copy of the list:

```
public static void Sort<T,U>(this List<T> list, Func<T, U> expression)
    where U : IComparable<U>
{
    list.Sort((x, y) => expression.Invoke(x).CompareTo(expression.Invoke(y)));
}
```

To use it:

```
myList.Sort(x=> x.myProperty);
```

I recently built this additional one which accepts an `ICompare<U>`, so that you can customize the comparison.  This came in handy when I needed to do a Natural string sort:

```
public static void Sort<T, U>(this List<T> list, Func<T, U> expression, IComparer<U> comparer)
    where U : IComparable<U>
{    
    list.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(expression.Invoke(x), expression.Invoke(y)));
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this, works fine.  I added an "isAscending = true" parameter.  To sort in descending order, simply swap the x and y around within the two Invoke() methods.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're just going to compile the expression you may as well just accept a delegate to begin with.  Additionally, this approach has major problems if the selector causes side effects, is expensive to compute, or is not deterministic.  A proper sorting based on a selected expression needs to invoke the selector no more than once per item in the list.

Comment: @Servy - those are all valid points, but I'll be honest, I'm not sure how to implement some of yoursuggestions (especially stopping a selector from causing side effects...?). I've changed them to delegates.  If you know how to make some of those changes, I would be happy to have you edit my code.

Comment: @Peter You *can't* prevent the delegates from causing side effects.  What you can do is ensure they're never called more than once per object, this means computing the values for each object, storing the object/projected-value pairs, and then sorting *that*.  `OrderBy` does all of that internally.

Answer (score 8):

Anybody working with nullable types, `Value` is required to use `CompareTo`.

```cs
objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => x.YourNullableType.Value.CompareTo(y.YourNullableType.Value));
```

Answer (score 5):

Please let me complete the answer by @LukeH with some sample code, as I have tested it I believe it may be useful for some:

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public Order(string orderId, DateTime orderDate, int quantity, int total)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        OrderDate = orderDate;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Total = total;
    }
}

public void SampleDataAndTest()
{
    List<Order> objListOrder = new List<Order>();

    objListOrder.Add(new Order("tu me paulo ", Convert.ToDateTime("01/06/2016"), 1, 44));
    objListOrder.Add(new Order("ante laudabas", Convert.ToDateTime("02/05/2016"), 2, 55));
    objListOrder.Add(new Order("ad ordinem ", Convert.ToDateTime("03/04/2016"), 5, 66));
    objListOrder.Add(new Order("collocationem ", Convert.ToDateTime("04/03/2016"), 9, 77));
    objListOrder.Add(new Order("que rerum ac ", Convert.ToDateTime("05/02/2016"), 10, 65));
    objListOrder.Add(new Order("locorum ; cuius", Convert.ToDateTime("06/01/2016"), 1, 343));


    Console.WriteLine("Sort the list by date ascending:");
    objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => x.OrderDate.CompareTo(y.OrderDate));

    foreach (Order o in objListOrder)
        Console.WriteLine("OrderId = " + o.OrderId + " OrderDate = " + o.OrderDate.ToString() + " Quantity = " + o.Quantity + " Total = " + o.Total);

    Console.WriteLine("Sort the list by date descending:");
    objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => y.OrderDate.CompareTo(x.OrderDate));
    foreach (Order o in objListOrder)
        Console.WriteLine("OrderId = " + o.OrderId + " OrderDate = " + o.OrderDate.ToString() + " Quantity = " + o.Quantity + " Total = " + o.Total);

    Console.WriteLine("Sort the list by OrderId ascending:");
    objListOrder.Sort((x, y) => x.OrderId.CompareTo(y.OrderId));
    foreach (Order o in objListOrder)
        Console.WriteLine("OrderId = " + o.OrderId + " OrderDate = " + o.OrderDate.ToString() + " Quantity = " + o.Quantity + " Total = " + o.Total);

    //etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//Get data from database, then sort list by staff name:

List<StaffMember> staffList = staffHandler.GetStaffMembers();

var sortedList = from staffmember in staffList
                 orderby staffmember.Name ascending
                 select staffmember;
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of LiNQ [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx#OrderBySimple1)

```
List<Order> objListOrder=new List<Order> ();
    objListOrder=GetOrderList().OrderBy(o=>o.orderid).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

An improved of Roger's version.

The problem with GetDynamicSortProperty is that only get the property names but what happen if in the GridView we use NavigationProperties? it will send an exception, since it finds null.

Example:

"Employee.Company.Name; " will crash... since allows only "Name" as a parameter to get its value.

Here's an improved version that allows us to sort by Navigation Properties.

```
public object GetDynamicSortProperty(object item, string propName)
    {
        try
        {                 
            string[] prop = propName.Split('.'); 

            //Use reflection to get order type                   
            int i = 0;                    
            while (i < prop.Count())
            {
                item = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop[i]).GetValue(item, null);
                i++;
            }                     

            return item;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something more generic about the properties selection yet be specific about the type you're selecting from, in your case 'Order':

write your function as a generic one:

```
public List<Order> GetOrderList<T>(IEnumerable<Order> orders, Func<Order, T> propertySelector)
        {
            return (from order in orders
                    orderby propertySelector(order)
                    select order).ToList();
        }
```

and then use it like this:

```
var ordersOrderedByDate = GetOrderList(orders, x => x.OrderDate);
```

You can be even more generic and define an open type for what you want to order:

```
public List<T> OrderBy<T,P>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T,P> propertySelector)
        {
            return (from item in collection
                    orderby propertySelector(item)
                    select item).ToList();
        }
```

and use it the same way:

```
var ordersOrderedByDate = OrderBy(orders, x => x.OrderDate);
```

Which is a stupid unnecessary complex way of doing a LINQ style 'OrderBy',
But it may give you a clue of how it can be implemented in a generic way

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = db.Items.Where...

var orderBYItemId = obj.OrderByDescending(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ID));
```

Answer (score 3):

Extension methods to sort lists in-place. It has a similar signature and null handling as LINQ OrderBy.

```
public static void SortBy<T, TKey>(this List<T> list, Func<T, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
{
    comparer ??= Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    list.Sort((a, b) => comparer.Compare(selector(a), selector(b)));
}

public static void SortByDescending<T, TKey>(this List<T> list, Func<T, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
{
    comparer ??= Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    list.Sort((a, b) => comparer.Compare(selector(b), selector(a)));
}
```

Usage:

```
items.SortBy(x => x.FullName);
items.SortBy(x => x.FullName, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

ValueTuples provide a convenient way to sortBy + thenBy in same the direction with default comparers:

```
items.SortBy(x => (x.FirstName, x.LastName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following code, in this code, we have a Passenger class with a couple of properties that we want to sort based on.

```
public class Passenger
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string PassportNo { get; }
    public string Nationality { get; }

    public Passenger(string name, string lastName, string passportNo, string nationality)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.PassportNo = passportNo;
        this.Nationality = nationality;
    }

    public static int CompareByName(Passenger passenger1, Passenger passenger2)
    {
        return String.Compare(passenger1.Name, passenger2.Name);
    }

    public static int CompareByLastName(Passenger passenger1, Passenger passenger2)
    {
        return String.Compare(passenger1.LastName, passenger2.LastName);
    }

    public static int CompareNationality(Passenger passenger1, Passenger passenger2)
    {
        return String.Compare(passenger1.Nationality, passenger2.Nationality);
    }
}

public class TestPassengerSort
{
    Passenger p1 = new Passenger("Johon", "Floid", "A123456789", "USA");
    Passenger p2 = new Passenger("Jo", "Sina", "A987463215", "UAE");
    Passenger p3 = new Passenger("Ped", "Zoola", "A987855215", "Italy");

    public void SortThem()
    {
        Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[] { p1, p2, p3 };
        List<Passenger> passengerList = new List<Passenger> { p1, p2, p3 };

        Array.Sort(passengers, Passenger.CompareByName);
        Array.Sort(passengers, Passenger.CompareByLastName);
        Array.Sort(passengers, Passenger.CompareNationality);

        passengerList.Sort(Passenger.CompareByName);
        passengerList.Sort(Passenger.CompareByLastName);
        passengerList.Sort(Passenger.CompareNationality);

    }
}
```

So you can implement your sort structure by using Composition delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **GenericTypeTea**'s Comparer :
we can obtain more flexibility by adding sorting flags :

```
public class MyOrderingClass : IComparer<Order> {  
    public int Compare(Order x, Order y) {  
        int compareDate = x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date);  
        if (compareDate == 0) {  
            int compareOrderId = x.OrderID.CompareTo(y.OrderID);  

            if (OrderIdDescending) {  
                compareOrderId = -compareOrderId;  
            }  
            return compareOrderId;  
        }  

        if (DateDescending) {  
            compareDate = -compareDate;  
        }  
        return compareDate;  
    }  

    public bool DateDescending { get; set; }  
    public bool OrderIdDescending { get; set; }  
}
```

In this scenario, you must instantiate it as **MyOrderingClass** explicitly( rather then **IComparer** )
in order to set its sorting properties :

```
MyOrderingClass comparer = new MyOrderingClass();  
comparer.DateDescending = ...;  
comparer.OrderIdDescending = ...;  
orderList.Sort(comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers were generic enough for me so I made this one:

```
var someUserInputStringValue = "propertyNameOfObject i.e. 'Quantity' or 'Date'";
var SortedData = DataToBeSorted
                   .OrderBy(m => m.GetType()
                                  .GetProperties()
                                  .First(n => 
                                      n.Name == someUserInputStringValue)
                   .GetValue(m, null))
                 .ToList();
```

Careful on massive data sets though. It's easy code but could get you in trouble if the collection is huge and the object type of the collection has a large number of fields.
Run time is NxM where:

N = # of Elements in collection

M = # of Properties within Object

Answer (score 1):

- If you need to sort the Id that is string in Question entity
- Use Sort function and delegate to sort the Id after parsing the Id
  value

```
    class Question
    {
        public List<QuestionInfo> Questions Info{ get; set; }
    
    }

    class QuestionInfo
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string Questions{ get; set; }
    
    }

    var questionnaire = new Question();
     questionnaire.QuestionInfo.Sort((x, y) => int.Parse(x.Id, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) - int.Parse(y.Id, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this extension method for `List<T>`.

The extension method takes the property you wish to sort as a parsed string and then uses the `OrderBy` method of the `List<T>`. Then it sets each index of the original list to the same index of the ordered list.

```
public static class ListExtensions {
    public static void SortBy<T>(this List<T> list, string property, bool reverse = false) {
        List<T> ordered = list.OrderBy(obj => obj.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(obj, null)).ToList();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            list[i] = reverse ? ordered[list.Count - 1 - i] : ordered[i];
    }
}
```

If an object in the list has the property `Name` you sort your list `testList` as so:

```
//For normal sorting order
testList.SortBy("Name");
//For reverse sorting order
testList.SortBy("Name", true);
```

I would recommend that you change the name of `SortBy`, to something like `Prefix_SortBy`. To prevent potential collisions if you import another library.

I know this method works for alphabetical and numerical ordering. Its sorting capabilites may be limited yet it is very simple to operate.

If there are some major flaws or issues with this, do tell, I've been programming C# for about 3 months.

Best regards

Comment: -1 using reflection is not a good idea for this kind of code. Using generic selector functions ( x=>x.Name ) enables a strongly-typed way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view the best is to use a sorted list so that data is sorted as it is added to result.
Other approaches need at least one extra iteration on data and most create a copy of data so not only performance but memory usage will be affected too. Might not be an issue with couple of hundreds of elements but will be with thousands, especially in services where many concurrent requests may do sorting at the same time.
Have a look at System.Collections.Generic namespace and choose a class with sorting instead of List.

And avoid generic implementations using reflection when possible, this can cause performance issues too.

Comment: How can this be more performant? Inserting data to a sorted list is O(n), so adding n items is O(n^2). What it many concurrent items are trying to be added? There are situations when you have extra CPU cycles to burn while items are being added, but this is not a good general solution.

Answer (score 0):

hi just to come back at the question.
If you want to sort the List of this sequence  "1" "10" "100" "200" "2" "20" "3" "30" "300" and get the sorted items in this form 1;2;3;10;20;30;100;200;300 you can use this:

```
 public class OrderingAscending : IComparer<String>
    {
        public int Compare(String x, String y)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(x, out var xtmp);
            Int32.TryParse(y, out var ytmp);

            int comparedItem = xtmp.CompareTo(ytmp);
            return comparedItem;
        }
    }
```

and you can use it in code behind in this form:

```
 IComparer<String> comparerHandle = new OrderingAscending();
 yourList.Sort(comparerHandle);
```