# Sort list of object by properties c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have this class:

```
public class Leg
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function that gets a list of legs, called GetLegs()

```
List<Leg> legs = GetLegs();
```

Now I would like to sort this list. So I first have to consider the day, then the hour, and at last the minute. 
How should I solve this sorting?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the native `DateTime` struct? Comparison and therefore sorting supported out of the box. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: By the way - look at the related questions to the right - there's lots of similar threads, you need to learn to search a bit. One for example (first one I looked at)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: As you see, it's my first post here, so I will probably get more used to how things work ;) Thanks for the reply anyway, I can't use DateTime in this scenario unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
List<Leg> legs = GetLegs()
                .OrderBy(o=>o.Day)
                .ThenBy(o=>o.Hour)
                .ThenBy(o=>o.Min).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom `IComparer<Leg>` and pass it to the `List<T>.Sort` method.

Alternatively, you can implement `IComparable<Leg>` in your class and simply call `List<T>.Sort`.

Comment: No need to do even that, he can just write an anonymous lambda in `List<T>.Sort`.

Comment: For reasons of code reuse, implementing `IComparable<T>` can be the better alternative if sorting / comparing should happen at more than one location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `IComparable<T>` interface on your class to allow a more intuitive way for the objects to be sorted in the C# language. When a class implements `IComparable`, you must also implement the `public method` `CompareTo(T).`

`Leg`  class implements `IComparable<Leg>`, which means an `Leg` instance can be compared with other `Leg`  instances.

```
    #region "Leg Class that implements IComparable interface"
    public class Leg:IComparable<Leg>
    {
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Hour { get; set; }
        public int Min { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Leg leg)
        {
            if (this.Day == leg.Day)
            {
                if (this.Hour == leg.Hour)
                {
                    return this.Min.CompareTo(leg.Min);
                }
            }
            return this.Day.CompareTo(leg.Day);
        }
    }
    #endregion


   //Main code
   List<Leg> legs = GetLegs();
   legs.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) Method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help.

```
var o = legs.OrderBy(x => x.Day)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Hour)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Min);
```