# How to sort a list by a specific property in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, syntax

In .NET 4.0 you can simply use LINQ to quickly sort a list by a specific property:

```
  List<Point> list = ...;    
  sorted = list.OrderBy(p => p.X).ToList(); // sort list of points by X
```

Can you do something similar when you cannot use .NET 4.0 LINQ syntax?

Is there a one-liner sort syntax?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309397/447156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a delegate, almost a one-liner :)

```
list.Sort(delegate(Point p1, Point p2){
        return p1.X.CompareTo(p2.X);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method, that takes `Comparison<T>`. Avaliable from `.NET 2.0`

```
var list = new List<Point>{ /* populate list */ };

list.Sort(Comparison);


public int Comparison (Point a, Point b)
{
    //do logic comparison with a and b
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I want to sort by a specific property, when it is a list of objects.