# C# List Sort All elements

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How can I sort a list by id in c# that contains `Book` items?

```
static List<Book> sorted = new List<Book>();

public string title { get; set; }
public string summary { get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public int numberofauthors { get; set; }
public string author {get; set;}
```

But I want to sort the whole list and not only the `sorted[k].id` column.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the whole list and not only the `id` column"? When you sort it on `id`, you *do* sort the entire list, where for each element of the result the `id` field is equal or greater than the `id` property of the previous item.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If so, what specifically have you tried?  What was the result of that attempt?  Have you done some research online as to how others have attempted to solve similar problems?  If so, how have other people attempted to solve this problem?  Have you tried to adapt those solutions to your situation?

Comment: You might try any of the answers described in this question especially if you are uncomfortable with LINQ. As your question is a bit ambiguous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: Searching "[C#] How to sort a list of objects by property" would have been a great way to save time :) The answers are already out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#.NET :How to Sort a List <T> by a property in the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Answer (score 2):

Try LINQ:

```
var sortedList = sorted.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();
```

Comment: do or do not. there is no try.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted.OrderBy(book => book.id);
```

Is this what you're thinking of?
Or perhaps this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

I'm sure this question has been answered plenty of times. Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) which does sort this list instead of `Enumerable.OrderBy` + `ToList` what creates a new list. Therefore you need to implement `IComparable<Book>`

```
class Book : IComparable<Book>
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int numberofauthors { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Book other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;

        return id.CompareTo(other.id);
    }
}
```

Now this works:

```
books.Sort();
```

Without changing your class you could also use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) with a custom `Comparison<Book>`:

```
books.Sort((b1, b2) => b1.id.CompareTo(b2.id));
```