# Get the files information

Tags: c#

I want to get the all the files sizes from the directory that I pass to the class and I want them to be sorted by their extension for example:

```
.exe:  
file1.exe ....... 254KB
file1.exe ....... 544KB
file1.exe ....... 254KB
```

If their was any other extensions want them to be written like this

Below is the code I wrote so far but I don't know how to sort the data:

```
public FileTools(string directoryPath,string searchPattern)
{
    DirectoryPath = directoryPath;
    SearchPattern = searchPattern;
    TotallFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
    CalculateFiles();
}
private void CalculateFiles()
{
  foreach (var item in new DirectoryInfo(this.DirectoryPath).GetFiles(SearchPattern,SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {

     }
 }
```

I want the `FileInfo` objects filled in a `List` and then sort and write them like the example.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  The internet is CHOCK FULL of example code demonstrating how to sort collections.

Comment: Duplicate of [C#.NET :How to Sort a List <T> by a property in the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your files by extension, and order the groups. Then you can have the output by looping on each extension. See this sample:

```
private void CalculateFiles()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var fileGroupByExtension = new DirectoryInfo(this.DirectoryPath)
                                    .GetFiles(SearchPattern,SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                    .GroupBy(file => file.Extension)
                                    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key);
    foreach (var grp in fileGroupByExtension)
    {
        var extension = grp.Key;
        builder.Append(extension);
        builder.Append(":");
        builder.AppendLine();
        foreach (var file in grp.OrderBy(file => file.Name))
        {
            builder.Append(file.Name);
            builder.Append(" ....... ");
            builder.Append(file.Length / 1000);
            builder.Append("KB");
            builder.AppendLine();
        }
    }
    Console.Write(builder.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    var sortedList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        directoryPath, 
        searchPattern, 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderBy(item => Path.GetExtension(item));
```

Remember to include `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, using LINQ:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(this.DirectoryPath).GetFiles(SearchPattern,SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var ordered_files = from f in files
                    orderby f.Extension
                    select f;
```