# Create custom collection class inheriting from List<> & override the sort method

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have class called Order in C# .Net 4.0. I want to create a custom collection class that inherits from the List class. I then want to know how to override the sort method on the List class to implement my own sort method.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like fries with that? We want to see your attempts first before we help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question looks quite similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/c-net-how-to-sort-a-list-t-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, as `List<T>.Sort()` has a few [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that let you specify the way to compare objects, altering the sort results.