# How to sort by alphabetically using struct and arraylist with c#

Tags: c#

THX ALL OF YOU .USING LIST<> INSTEAD ARRAYLIST IS RLY HELPFULL

So i heave a struct, wich contain information about worker, fio-name of worker, dolj-his job, staj-how much he working on this job and zp-how much money he takes, this info i keep in file with strings,  expl:Nick, road-worker, 5,200. I have 8 thoose string like expl, and i need to sort them by the name of worker, using arraylist and struct, plz help !

```
//Struct
 public struct Worker
{
    public string FIO;
    public string Dolj;
    public int Staj;
    public int Zp;
    public Worker(string fi, string dj, int st, int zrp)
    {
        FIO = fi;
        Dolj = dj;
        Staj = st;
        Zp = zrp;
    }
//reading from file

ArrayList listw = new ArrayList();
            Worker W;
            StreamReader file= new StreamReader("Workers.txt", Encoding.Default);
          ;
            while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] wtemp = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
                W = new Worker(wtemp[0],wtemp[1],Convert.ToInt32(wtemp[2]),Convert.ToInt32(wtemp[3]));
                listw.Add(W);
            }

//display listw
//!!!!! So here i need to sort arraylist or struct by FIO (name of worker)
// Arraylist - listw 
// (Name,job,years,money)
// (Name,job,years,money) --Sort by name!

 foreach (Worker outworker in listw)
            {

                Console.WriteLine
                (outworker.FIO,outworker.Dolj,outworker.Staj,outworker.Zp);
            }
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, use the generic type `List<Worker>`.

Comment: By using Linq you can use `listw.OrderBy(w => w.FIO)`

Comment: Use a `List<Worker>` instead of an ArrayList. Make `Worker` a class that implements `IComparable<Worker>` and define how two workers should be compared (i.e. sorted). Then you can use the Sort method to sort the list easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//reading from file

```
List<Worker> listw = new List<Worker>();
Worker W;
StreamReader file= new StreamReader("Workers.txt", Encoding.Default);

while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] wtemp = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
    W = new Worker(wtemp[0],wtemp[1],Convert.ToInt32(wtemp[2]),Convert.ToInt32(wtemp[3]));
    listw.Add(W);
}

//Sort by name.
listw = listw.OrderBy(x=> x.FIO).ToList();

foreach (Worker outworker in listw)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outworker.FIO,outworker.Dolj,outworker.Staj,outworker.Zp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
var orderedWorkers = listw.OfType<Worker>().OrderBy(x => x.FIO).ToList();
```

Also always use `List<T>` class instead of `ArrayList`, for type safety.

Another alternative is implementing a custom `Comparer` for your type:

```
public struct NameComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is Worker && y is Worker)
        {
            return ((Worker)x).FIO.CompareTo(((Worker)y).FIO);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then just call [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx) method:

```
 listw.Sort(new NameComparer());
```

Comment: +1 for common sense people still use ArrayList?? Jeez

Answer (score 0):

Change your listw type to `List<Worker>` and you can do a LINQ sort easily.

```
foreach (var outworker in listw.OrderBy(worker => worker.FIO))
{
    Console.WriteLine(outworker.FIO, outworker.Dolj, outworker.Staj, outworker.Zp);
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, you can't call linq methods directly on ArrayList.

Comment: Thats why I said change to `List<Worker>` as I recommended in my comment below his question. ArrayList shouldn't be used at all nowadays.