# At least one object must implement IComparable calling OrderBy()

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I already saw this question, but i didn't find my happiness with the answers...

I'm trying to do that:

```
var coll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ArticleJSON>>(json);
coll = coll.OrderBy(a => a.tags).Distinct().ToList();
```

Throws an error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

For the moment i didn't find the solution so i did that:

```
List<string> categories = new List<string>();    
var coll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ArticleJSON>>(json);

for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < test[i].tags.Count; ++j)
    {
        _categories.Add(test[i].tags[j]);
    }
}

categories = _categories.Distinct().ToList();
```

It works but i'm curious to know why the first one don't work.

EDIT :

My data come from a JSON :

```
            'tags': [ 

                                        'Pantoufle',
                                        'Patate'
                                     ]
                            },
            public List<string> tags { get; set; }
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand how to compare the tags.. What is the `tags` data type?

Comment: Implement the interface IComparable for the tags 's Type

Comment: *Implement the interface IComparable for the tags 's Type* -- that's not a useful comment, because the type of tags is `List<string>`.

Comment: Check this out for a `Linq` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309230/3543437

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To order a set of things, there must be a way to compare two things to determine which one is larger, or smaller or whether they are equal. Any c# type that implements the `IComparable` interface, provides the means to compare it versus another instance.

Your `tags` field is a list of strings. There is no standard way to compare two lists of strings in that manner. The type `List<string>` does not implement the `IComparable` interface, and thus cannot be used in a LINQ `OrderBy` expression.

If for example you wanted to order the articles by the number of tags, you could do that like this:

```
coll = coll.OrderBy(a => a.tags.Count).ToList();
```

because `Count` will return an integer and an integer is comparable.

If you wanted to get all unique tags in sorted order, you could do that like this:

```
var sortedUniqueTags = coll
    .SelectMany(a => a.Tags)
    .OrderBy(t => t)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

because a string is comparable.

If you really know how to compare two lists of strings, you could write your own custom comparer:

```
public class MyStringListComparer : IComparer<List<string>>
{
    // implementation
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var comparer = new MyStringListComparer();
coll = coll.OrderBy(a => a.tags, comparer).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to solve this for over an hour.

Answer (score 1):

ArticleJSON does not implement IComparable while String does. The compiler does not know how to compare ArticleJSON for the OrderBy() you are calling. It works fine when you are using a list of string because of this.

Comment: No. The OP is comparing tags, which are `List<string>`. Lists (as opposed to their contents) don't have a defined order.

Comment: Mine doing this _objList = _objList.OrderBy(rr => new { rr.xa, rr.xb }).ToList(); would not work but it works when I separated them like .OrderBy(rr=>rr.xa).ThenBy(rr => rr.xb ).ToList();  Still don't know why the former does not work.