# Trying to group by distinct values and add results to a listview

Tags: c#, linq, listview

as the title says, I'm trying to group a selection by it's distinct values, and then iterate through the result to populate a listView of checkboxes, my code is below

```
var checkBoxAdd =
            from sale in saleData
            orderby sale.City.ToList()
            group sale.City by sale.City.Distinct() into cityDistinct
            select cityDistinct;


foreach (House s in checkBoxAdd)
{
    listViewCities.Items.Add(s.City.ToString());
}
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this please

Comment: What is the type of sale.City, does it implement IComparable?

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465104/at-least-one-object-must-implement-icomparable-calling-orderby

Comment: Your results are a List<List<List<object>>>.  The groups is the first list and the last two are the rows and columns of a table.

Answer (score 0):

That is happen because chekBoxAdd contains no `House` Objects. Your checkBoxAdd is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<IEnumerable<char>, string>>`.
You're trying to compare `House` object with `IGrouping<IEnumerable<char>, string>` element.