# Take items from List and put it in some other List C#

Tags: c#, .net

My question is, how to take from this List

```
Periods = new List<TimePeriod>
                  {
                    new TimePeriod
                      {
                        Id = "Today",
                        Start = DateTime.Now.Date,
                        // date without seconds
                        End = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1) // last before next day
                      },

                    new TimePeriod
                      {
                        Id = "Yesterday",
                        Start = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1),
                        End = DateTime.Now.Date.AddTicks(-1),
                      },

                    new TimePeriod
                      {
                        Id = "CurrentWeek",
                        Start = DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfWeek(),
                        End = DateTime.Now.LastDayOfWeek().AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
                      },

                    new TimePeriod
                      {
                        Id = "LastWeek",
                        Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).FirstDayOfWeek(),
                        End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).LastDayOfWeek().AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
                      },
```

only Ids(Today,Yesterday,CurrentWeek,LastWeek) and put them in some other List, so i can sort them in my function

```
public void FillDefaultPeriods(int offsetInMinutes,List<string> ordering)
```

with ordering parameter( for example i will put in parameter later "Yesterday","Today","LastWeek","CurrentWeek"). The order will be not the same like in Periods List

Comment: Are you sure you've posted relevant sorting method code? Your `FillDefaultPeriods` doesn't attempt to sort anything.

Comment: How do you want sort? Based on Start Time or End Time?

Comment: no no, in that method i want to put Id values from Periods in some List and than sort that list. Argument ordering will give me the order of the new List

Comment: So you want to order based on the Arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: Start time and End time are no relevant, i want sorting based on Periods Id's("Today","Yesterday","Last Month"...). Now i have sorting like Today,Yesterday,.. , but i want to have method that will have parameter for sorting

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not quite clear how your posted `FillDefaultPeriods` relevant to your declared goal "put those Id ("Today","Yesterday".. in some other List) and then sort them", but this goal can easily be achieved by:

```
var list = Periods.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
list.Sort();
```

Update

This will sort list using defult string comparer. If you need some custom comparing option - you can use override of `List.Sort` method takes `Comparison<T>` as argument and write your own comparison rules

like this:

```
var list = Periods.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
list.Sort(MyCustomComparison);

....

private static int MyCustomComparison(string x, string y)
{
   ... your comparing logic here.
}
```

In `MyCustomComparison` method you have to write your comparing logic. This method should return negative value if `x` is "less" than `y` by you logic, zero if they are equals and positive value if `x` "greater" than `y`.

Comment: Actually the OP wants to be sorted the list based on the parameter.

Comment: Ok but how to make the sort order by my taste ? With your code i will list all the Id and put in var list. But how how to make sorting in that list with parameter in the function. For example if i want Yesterday to be my first item, Today my second.. or maybe i will want next time to have today first, Yesterday second

Comment: Yes i want to have sorting bu parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the periods themselves in a particular order and not only have their ids sorted, you could go with this:

```
var orderedPeriods = Periods.OrderBy(p => p.Id);
```

This will use default string comparison on ids. Of course, you can provide another key deriving function if you want something more sophisticated.