# Order List<Object> by property name

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class Test
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
List<Test> values = new List<Test>()  //contains 10 items
```

Some Items in the list their Value property can start with the character `>`

Example:

```
 Name
 Something 
 Example
 > Another one
 Demo
 Student
 > Home
```

How can I sort my list of objects so that the first items in the list are sorted alphabetically and the ones that start with `>` are sorted alphabetically as well but are at the end of the list?

This is what I did so far:

```
values.Where(x => !x.Value.StartsWith(">")).OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: And why are you trieng to do everything in 1 line? You could first filter all Objects with a Value that stats with ">" out and then sort. So you could debug it better..

Comment: Please [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309293/3538012) at the duplicate question. You should sort everything by whether it has `>` or not, and then use `ThenBy()` (as shown in that answer) to sort alphabetically. If you make an attempt to implement that but have trouble, please ask a new question, and include in that question [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates whatever difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 2):

you would need to calculate a key to sort by

```
List<Test> ordered = values.OrderBy(v => 
         v.Value.StartsWith(">") ? "ZZ" + v.Value : v.Value
).ToList();
```

"ZZ" is an arbitrary key that will sort the values starting with ">" after all English terms. (Being the last letter in the alphabet and no English words starting with two Zs). SInce ">" has a lower byte value than any letter one `Z` is not enough, since any valid english term would sort after anything staring with `Z>`

Comment: What's the purpose of the "Z" ?

Comment: @user2818430 Moves them to the end of the sort order.

Comment: Seams one `Z` does the work! Thanks :)

Comment: This particular approach may address the OP's need, but it's not easily generalized. It would be better for the OP to solve this the _right_ way, rather than using a hack like this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well it could be two "zz" but one is not enough. `Zebra`would sort after `Z>last`

Comment: @user2818430 one is not enough. See the update

Comment: @PeterDuniho the generalized form is in the first line "Calculate a key to sort by". THe code is an example of doing that