# Sort a List<string[]> by the second value (int)

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list

```
List<string[]> listname = ...
```

The list looks like this:

```
[string][string][string]
```

I want to sort the list by second string.

The second string is a number presented as a string, i want to keep it that way, i need it like this.

I want the numbers to be in Increasing order.

Example for data:

```
["RDP"]["3389"]["TCP"] 
["HTTP"]["80"]["TCP"]
["HTTPS"]["443"]["TCP"]
```

I want to sort by the post number.

In this example "RDP" will become the last one.

How can I do so?

Comment: Please give us an example of the contents of the list. As you have phrased it currently, it's hard to understand.

Comment: See duplicate. Just as you'd do with `.OrderBy(f => f.Foo)` you can use `.OrderBy(f => f[1])`.

Comment: ["HTTP"]["80"]["TCP"], This is an example for data/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: @CodeCaster Tried but it not sorting them...

Comment: Yes, it does. If you think it doesn't, create an example (which doesn't need external data) that reproduces the problem, and explain what you'd expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: I dont find a solution to my answer in what you posted. I am editing my question

Comment: You didn't show any code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedList = listname.OrderBy(l => int.Parse(l[1]));
```

This assumes that the second entry in each array is parsable as `int`. If you're not sure about that, you'd need to add some checks and maybe use `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to appropriate index of an array in `OrderBy`:

```
var l = new List<string[]>() { 
                                new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }, 
                                new string[] { "b", "a", "c" }, 
                                new string[] { "c", "c", "c" }, 
                                };
var s = l.OrderBy(c => c[1]).ToList();
```