# How can I sort a List<Issue> by date

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I need to sort the list:

```
List <Issue> usersissueslist = new List <Issue>();
```

I want to sort it by the property of a regular Issue:

```
Issue.startDate
```

The startDate format is a dateTime , "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

For example :

```
usersissueslist[0].startDate="10.9.15"    usersissueslist[1].startDate="8.9.15"       usersissueslist[2].startDate="9.9.15"
```

After the sort:

```
usersissueslist[0].startDate="8.9.15"        usersissueslist[1].startDate="9.9.15"        usersissueslist[2].startDate="10.9.15"
```

I WANT TO TO CHANGE THE ISSUE POSITION IN THE LIST AND NOT THE ISSUE STARTDATE.

tnx.

Comment: Is `startDate` a DateTime type or a String?

Comment: Don't want to be harsh, but did you even try search for something like *'C# list sort'*, which eventually lead you to [List<T>.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w56d4y5z(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: assuming StartDate is of DateTime type. Try this: List<Issue> sortedList = usersissueslist.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Sorting date saved as string will only work when your date format is `year.month.day`. If you can't (or do not want) use `DateTime` variable to store date you will have to write your own comparer for 'Issue' or override `Equals` method. I'd advice to use proper type for `DateTime` instead of string.

Comment: The startDate format is a dateTime , "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Then you would have to write a special comparer to sort it when you store it as string. But this is pointless work - store you startDate as `DateTime` and this (and possibly future) problems will be gone. I can't think of any reason to store date as string.

Comment: I just told you that it isn't a string hhh
So how should i sort it?

Comment: `var sorted = usersissueslist.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();` - see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is using linq, assuming your StartDate property is of type `string`.

```
 var sortedList = usersissueslist.OrderBy(item => item.StartDate).ToList();
```

As suggested by everyone.

Comment: The startDate format is a dateTime , "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"