# C# : Sort list on custom property

Tags: c#, sorting

I am sorry if this is duplicate. Please point to correct question.

I have a class called MyDate like below

```
public class MyDate
{
    private SqlDateTime m_dateTime;

    public MyDate(DateTime dateTime)
    {
       if (DateTime.Compare(dateTime, (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue) <= 0)
            m_dateTime = SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        else
            m_dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public string MMDDYYYYHHMMSS
    {
       get
         {
            if(m_dateTime > SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                return m_dateTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            else
                return String.Empty;
         }
    }
}
```

I have class called MyEvent like below

```
public class MyEvent
{
  public int EventId{get;set;}
  public MyDate StartDate{get;set;}
}
```

I have collection of MyEvent like

```
List<MyEvent> myEvents.
```

Now I need to sort myEvents in descending order of StartDate. The problem I have is I cannot add IComparable or change MyDate since it is written by other team and I just refer dll. I donot have control on MyDate code. Can anybody help me how I can do. I created a new comparer class that implements IComparer but unable to understand how to use it and sort myEvents.

**UPDATE 1 **

Thank you very much for Alexei, Ehsan and Dave for helping me out. I tried Dave's answer and it worked. I was trying to do it in more better way so that there is no need to add any new properties. I didnot try Ehsan way of using StringDateComparer but it helped me to understand how I can use Comparer in Order linq statements. At last as pointed by Alexei I did like below

**UPDATE 2 **

Sometimes I am getting empty string for e2.StartDate.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS and/or e2.StartDate.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS so I changed my code like below

```
myEvents.Sort(
                delegate(MyEvent e1, MyEvent e2)
                 {
                     DateTime dt1;
                     DateTime dt2;
                     DateTime.TryParse(e1.StartDateTime.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS, out dt1);
                     DateTime.TryParse(e2.StartDateTime.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS, out dt2);

                     return dt2.CompareTo(dt1); // descending
                     //return dt1.CompareTo(dt2); // ascending
                    }
            );
```

Comment: it not exact duplicate, OP scenario is different

Comment: A class that takes a `DateTime` converts to a `SqlDateTime` and only exposes a `string`?  Your real problem is this other team.

Comment: You've obviously seen what I believe is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object) of you question since it first link to search for title of your post (https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+%3A+Sort+list+on+custom+property). Please clarify why solutions suggested there did not work (including custom comparer) so it is clear that this post is not duplicate.

Comment: My scenario is different. In MyDate I donot have any DateTime property. So I cannot use any sort or order by methods. I was trying to avoid adding extra property in MyEvent class. I tried IComparer. All the examples I saw just jumped directly using OrderBy linq statement without showing how IComparer implementation came into picture...

Comment: @Ziggler http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309397/477420 shows perfect example of custom comparer...

Answer (score 3):

This might be inefficient, but you could add a `DateTime` property to your `MyEvent` class that converts `StartDate` to a `DateTime` and sort on that:

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public int EventId{get;set;}
    public MyDate StartDate{get;set;}
    public DateTime MyStartDate { get { return DateTime.Parse(StartDate.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS); } }
}

var sorted = myEvents.OrderByDescending(e => e.MyStartDate);
```

Alternatively, you could make the class immutable and do the conversion when instantiating it:

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public MyEvent(int eventId, MyDate startDate)
    {
        EventId = eventId;
        StartDate = startDate;
        MyStartDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS);
    }

    public int EventId{get; private set;}
    public MyDate StartDate{get; private set;}
    public DateTime MyStartDate { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: better yet would be to set the `MyStartDate` property when creating a `MyEvent` and making `MyEvent` immutable..

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and it worked. I was trying to do it in more better way so that there is no need to add any new properties

Answer (score 3):

You can write it with Linq `OrderyBy()` or `OrderByDescending` method according to your need this way:

```
var outputDate = myEvents.OrderByDescending(x=>
                          {
                           DateTime parsedDate;
                           return DateTime.TryParseExact(x.StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate) ? parsedDate : DateTime.MinValue;
                          });
```

or proper way would be to create a custom [IComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it:

```
public class StringDateComparer : IComparer<string>
{

    public int Compare(string date1, string date2)
    {
        DateTime parsedDate1;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate1);


        DateTime parsedDate2;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(date2, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate2);



        if (parsedDate1 < parsedDate2)
            return -1;
        if (parsedDate1 > parsedDate2)
            return 1;


        return 0;
    }
}
```

and now call `OrderByDescending()` overload which takes `IComparer` object as parameter:

```
var outputDate = myEvents.OrderByDescending(x=>x.StartDate,new StringDateComparer());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnot try this but it helped me to understand how I can use Comparer in Order linq statements