# Sort a list by className Alphabetic order

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm doing some exercise on Unity/C#, and for one of them I have a list that contain some inherited classes.

```
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

each Item is an inherited class like PowerUp,ConceptArt,Bonus who all iherit from Item...

I would like to, sort that list using the name of the item class.

Basically if i have list

```
myList = { Bonus,ConceptArt, PowerUp, PowerUp,ConceptArt }
```

if I sort it, the output would be :

```
myList = { Bonus,ConceptArt, ConceptArt, PowerUp,PowerUp}
```

How do I do that?

I don't know if I explained myself clearly. 
If i need to edit, tell me :)

thx :)

Comment: `myList = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList()` or something similar?

Comment: you can't easily sort by variable name however

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as that question is trying to sort based on a property of the list type, the OP is trying to sort based on the type of the object itself.

Comment: For future reference, the term you are referring to is inherit / inherited, not herit / herited.

Comment: thx @DarrenYoung will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
items = items.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I m doing maybe something bad, but it looks like  myList.orderBy don't exist in Unity.

Comment: How is this related to Unity?

Comment: Make sure that you have imported the `System.Linq` namespace at the start of your c# file. E.g. `using System.Linq;`

Comment: You right, I didn't had the using System.Linq; Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

To sort *in place*, without creating a *new* list:

```
  myList.Sort((Comparison<Item>) 
    ((left, right) => String.Compare(left.GetType().Name, right.GetType().Name)));
```

To check/test:

```
  String report = String.Join(", ", myList
    .Select(item => item.GetType().Name));

  Console.Write(report);
```