# How to write a generic sort extension

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, generic-list

How do I re-write this sort code sample so it's using a generic extension instead of the second line?

**I would like something like thi**

```
var foosSorted = Unit.Foos().MyGenericSortFunction();
```

**My working code**

```
var foosSorted = Unit.Foos(); // Not sorted yet
foosSorted.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

**How far I got with the generic extension**

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static T Sort<T>(this T list) where T : ???
    {
        return list.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can maybe solve it with this linq instead `    var foosSorted = Unit.GetFoos().OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();
` but I would still really like to know how to make this with a generic extion solution, because I am so bad with the generic part.

Comment: @Shiva yes I saw that question right after too. But I would still like to learn the generic alternative.

Comment: You should go with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26406452/1789202

Comment: @Shiva how's this duplicate? OP knows how to sort a list. Needs a generic way which is not in scope of duplicate link.

Comment: `OrderBy` *is* the generic solution. Why write another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend to make list elements generic? Like this:

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static List<T> Sort<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IFoo
    {
        list.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
        return list;
    }
}

public interface IFoo {
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Foo1 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should Foo1 and Foo2 extend from IFoo? Because if not it looks like something I understand.

Comment: I saw your comment *Because sometimes my class i Unit and sometimes it's Group*. So both of them should implement an interface, `IFoo`, for ex.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter should be the collection of your type, so you'll be able to treat it as a collection, and access the `Name` property:

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static List<Foo> MyGenericSortFunction(this List<Foo> list)
    {
        list.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
        return list;
    }
}
```

You wouldn't use a generic here because you specifically need to use `Name`, which is a property of your `Foo` class. If it was defined in an interface, you could make your extension generic to the interface.

Note that this edits the existing list, rather than returning a new list like LINQ would do.

Comment: Can you replace `Foo` with `T` ? Because sometimes my class i Unit and sometimes it's Group to be precise.

Comment: You could also pass an expression which points to the property you wanted to compare, like `MySort(x => x.Propname)`, that way you could compare any type for sorting

Comment: @radbyx Do your `Unit` and `Group` classes share an interface that exposes `Name`?  If not they you cannot make this generic, you'd have to use `dynamic` instead.

Comment: No they don't share an Interface. All they have in common is that the have a Name property. Can you make the dynamic solution instead then?

Comment: Is the name property the same type across the board?  Make an interface to support it, and use that interface.

Comment: Yes they are all `string`. You mean like creating and using your own `Comparator` ?