# Sorting a phone list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, text

I have an assignment where I have to sort a phone list by name. I have the following code. I know it's a mess and there are some things missing but it's what I got for now. Some variables are in Portuguese but I'll make my best to make it understandable. This is a different case where I am not allowed to use LINQ's or lists

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file= "nomes.txt";
    string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    // Reads line by line
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = text[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace (line [j-1]) == true)
                {
                    string[] palavra = line.Split(',');

                    if (char.IsDigit(line [j]) == true)
                    {
                        string[] nr = line.Split('-');
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

File looks like this:

```
 Joaquim Lopes da Silva 932 000 999
 Maria da Conceição Granja 91 384 75 34
 Herculano Lopes Vieira 253334556
```

Expected output:

```
Silva, Joaquim Lopes da - 932 000 999
Granja, Maria da Conceição - 913 847 534
Vieira, Herculano Lopes - 253 334 556
```

Comment: and how your txt file look like??

Comment: what is posletra ?

Comment: Check the edit. 
Posletra stands for the postion of each letter, it's commented there

Comment: The duplicate has answers which do not use LINQ either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309593/3314501

Answer (score 0):

First read all data into a List< Item >:

```
class Item {
    public string First;
    public string Second;
    ...
}
var items = ReadFromFile();
```

Then use LINQ:

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(entry, entry.First);
```

where entry.First is the string field for "Silva" or "Granja" etc.

Comment: I'm still on the basics so i should't use any advaced stuff. Only arrays, methods and loops. Also I want to know if my code is suitable for it yet.

Comment: is this advanced? It is quite primitive.

Comment: @HenriqueGuimarães, maybe you'll find that more array-friendly: var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(entry, entry.First).ToArray();

Comment: At this assignement I can't use the LINQ method