# Sort an array of objects by value in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an array of objects, each object containing a user id, and an amount of money. How would I sort this array to make the objects with the largest sum of money be the first elements in the array, and the last ones being the people with the least amount of money?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with LINQ `orderBy`

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void OrderByEx1()
{
    Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

    IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

    foreach (Pet pet in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by ascending :

```
 var newList = YourObj.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

Order by Descending:

```
  var newList = YourObj.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).ToList();
```

Comment: If you want to answer question with plenty of duplicates at least provide an answer. `List<T>` is not array.