# How do i sort my listview alphabetically?

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, xamarin

So i have this listview, and i want to make it alphabetically sorting. do someone know if you can do it? and if you know how you can do it, then show me the code. LOOKING FOR HELP!!

this is my Xaml.cs code:

```
namespace App2
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<Kontakter> kontakter = new List<Kontakter>
    {
        new Kontakter
        {
        Fuldenavn = "Name One (NO)",
        Tlfnr = 12345678
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Another Name (AN)",
            Tlfnr = 23456789
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Third Name (TN)",
            Tlfnr = 34567890
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Yet Another (YA)",
            Tlfnr = 45678901
        }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter;
    }

    private void MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var keyword = MainSearchBar.Text;
        NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter.Where(obj => (obj.Fuldenavn.Contains(keyword) || obj.Tlfnr.ToString().Contains(keyword)));
    }
}
}
```

this is my Xmal code:

```
<ListView x:Name="NameslistView" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Fuldenavn}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hey Kristian F, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: `.orderBy(...).thenBy(...).thenBy(...).thenBy(...)` if you need to sort multiple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the LINQ method [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)  for this.

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a
>   key.

```
var sorted = kontakter.OrderBy(x => x.Fuldenavn)
                      .ToList();
```

Have a read at [101 LINQ-Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for more information.

**EDIT**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Order the contacts
    var sorted = kontakter.OrderBy(x => x.Fuldenavn)
                          .ToList();

    //Set the ItemsSource with the ordered contacts
    NameslistView.ItemsSource = sorted;
}
```

Comment: @KristianF For example: `NameslistView.ItemsSource = sorted;`

Comment: I relly dont undestand what you mean. can you send the code how it shold be setuped? @Mighty Badaboom

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much :D @Mighty Badaboom

Comment: Your welcome.
But I would realy like to know why someone downvoted this...

Comment: probably because there are 1000 other questions on SO about sorting in C#

Comment: @Jason Yes there are. But it does not make my answer wrong..however

Answer (score 1):

use Sort and provide condition

kontakter.Sort((x, y) => x.Fuldenavn[0].CompareTo(y.Fuldenavn[0]));

where [0] represent 1st letter of Fuldenavn so that it will be sorted by alphabetical order.

Comment: You don't have to write your own compare logic when LINQ's `OrderBy` is doing this for you.

Comment: ooh ok 
Thank you@MightyBadaboom
.