# Try to sort a List of Object in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a c # object list, the object is composed like this: an `int num` and a `string alphabet`.
I wish a list like that :

```
 - element 1 : num : 2 alphabet : A
 - element 2 : num : 1 alphabet : A
 - element 3 : num : 1 alphabet : B
 - element 4 : num : 2 alphabet : B
 - element 5 : num : 2 alphabet : B
```

become like that :

```
 - element 1 : num : 1 alphabet : A
 - element 2 : num : 2 alphabet : A
 - element 3 : num : 1 alphabet : B
 - element 4 : num : 2 alphabet : B
 - element 5 : num : 2 alphabet : B
```

I already did that :

```
myList.Sort(MyObject p1, MyObject p2) {
  p1.num;
  p2.Type;
  //code but i don't know what
});
```

Does anyone know how to do it? thank you very much

Comment: By which rule should be sorted? Question unclear

Comment: `myList.OrderBy(x => x.Element)` ?

Comment: [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309188/669576)

Comment: Please show the actual implementation of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort existing list *inplace*:

```
myList.Sort((left, right) => {
  int r = string.Compare(left.alphabet, right.alphabet);

  if (r != 0)
    return r;
  else
    return left.num.CompareTo(right.num);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! This is exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

As apparently lexicographic sorting is desired, the list can be sorted using the Linq extension methods `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` (which are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)) as follows.

```
myList = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.alphabet).ThenBy(x => x.num).ToList();
```

Comment: the desired output has `num` descending in case of alphabet  `A` and `num` ascending in case of alphabet `B`

Comment: Yes but i work with huge list and if i use Linq, i will have a serious issue of performance, no ?