# C# How to sort a list of objects by any property

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

```
public class SortExample
{
  public int IntField {get; set;}

  public string StringField {get; set;}

  public DateTime DateField {get; set;}
}
```

This class is set as a source for a listview and the sortExpression param passed in function below is property name with sort order 'IntField ASC' 'IntField DESC' 'StringField ASC' 'StringField DESC'

```
public void SortExampleMethod(string sortExpression)
{
   List<SortExample> list = new  List<SortExample>();
   list.OrderBy(sortExpression);
}
```

Is the only way to implement this is to write a Comparator for every property or something in LINQ allows this to be done easily?

Comment: 'IntField ASC' 'IntField DESC'? How does that work?

Comment: That code doesn't even compile.

Comment: You can construct expression on the fly for any property.

Comment: I imagine you're looking for something like `list.OrderBy(x=>x.IntField).ThenByDescending(x=>x.StringField)`, but your question is so poor, it's hard to guess what you want.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: @Sinatr No it is not duplicate: read last line "Is the only way to implement this is to write a Comparator for every property or something in LINQ allows this to be done easily?" I think, he already knows this solution but want better solution (he might want reflection)

Comment: You want dynamic LINQ. The answer you're looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/3294832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you need, you can use LINQ Dynamic Query Library which allows you to pass `string` to your `OrderBy`.

ex: `var result = list.OrderBy("intField asc");`

Here full tutorial

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Another Solution is to make the method accepts `Expression` class

```
public void sort(Expression<Func<TEntity, S>> orderByExpression, bool ascending)
{

List<SortExample> list = new  List<SortExample>();
if(ascending)
{
   list.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
}
else
   list.OrderByDescneding(orderByExpression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My solution was a slight variation of this

 'list.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList()'

Answer (score -2):

Somthing like:

list.OrderBy(x => x.property);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Comment: oh dear! put some effort in explaining how he will effectively use it.

Comment: Hello Danny next time you post the answer give justifications and guidelines where the guy can follow