# How to Sort a List<T> by a another list in the object

Tags: c#

Please note to the following topic that has already been raised :

> [How to Sort a List by a property in the
>   object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

I want to sort a list by another list. I add to the list with the following command :

```
ListClass.Add(new item_util(items[b], util[b]));
```

Now based on the above topic , I can sort items by ascending :

```
List<item_util> SortedList = ListClass.OrderBy(o=>o.items).ToList();
```

I do not want to sort ascending. How can I sort items by another list (ListA)?

**Updated**

```
int[] items = {7, 4, 1};
int[] util  = {5, 11, 20};
var listA   = new List<int> {5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 3, 8, 6};

List<item_util> ListClass= new List<item_util>();
for (int b = 0; b < items.Length; b++)
    ListClass.Add(new item_util(items[b], util[b]));
List<item_util> SortedList = ListClass.OrderBy(o => o.item).ToList();
```

Currently `SortedList` output is equal to: `{(1,20),(4,11),(7,5)}`

But I want to sort the list acording to listA. So the output must be obtained as : `{(4, 11), (1, 20), (7, 5)}`

Because they are arranged in ListA as : {5, **4**, **1**, 2, **7**, 3, 8, 6}

Comment: Is it really too much work to write `var listA = new List<int> {5,4,1,2,7,3,8,6};` so that others can just copy/paste it? Please update your samples with code that actually compiles!

Comment: I updated the codes.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `item_util`? Did you see the suggestion of a [mcve]?

Comment: You also can't do `int.Parse(items[b])` - you can't parse an `int`.

Comment: This is problably one of the most horrifying questions ever. EVERYTHING has changed from the original question. Please close this.

Comment: @Amin: Why use a class (`item_util`) when you can use a value tuple?

Comment: @Amin - I have a performant answer for you. Please fix your question so that I know I'm posting the right answer.

Comment: Do not keep editing a question to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle large lists, and duplicates and missing values in `listA`, you need to do something like this:

```
var indices = listA.Select((x, n) => new { x, n }).ToLookup(y => y.x, y => y.n);

List<item_util> SortedList =
    ListClass
        .OrderBy(o => indices[o.item].Append(int.MaxValue).First())
        .ToList();
```

If `listA` becomes large then using `Array.IndexOf` will slow the code down immensely as it would be a `O(n^2)` operation. The `.ToLookup` generates an `O(n)` operation as far as the sort is concerned.

Also, if items are missing from `listA` the use of `.Append(int.MaxValue)` will push those values to the end of the sort.

---

If `.Append` is not available it must be because you're on an earlier version of the framework. It's built-in to mine.

Try this instead:

```
List<item_util> SortedList =
    ListClass
        .OrderBy(o => indices[o.item].Concat(new [] { int.MaxValue }).First())
        .ToList();
```

Comment: ListA is unique and the listA is a big list. recived a error : `'IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Append' and no extension method 'Append' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Amin - I've amended my answer for earlier versions of the framework,

Answer (score -3):

Your code doesn't make too much sense to me, but this will give you the idea and generates the output you are looking for:

```
var listA = new int [] {5,4,1,2,7,3,8,6};
var listB = new List<ListClass>
{
    new ListClass(1, 20),
    new ListClass(4, 11),
    new ListClass(7, 5)
};
var results = listB.OrderBy(p => Array.IndexOf(listA, p.X));

foreach (var r in results) Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", r.X, r.Y);
```

Result:

```
4, 11
1, 20
7, 5
```

Click this link to see the [example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBesPx)

Comment: The outputs he's looking for is `{(4,11),(1,20),(7,5)}` not `{(20,20),(11,11),(5,5)}`.

Comment: And since you're answer is almost exactly like my answer we have a serious problem that we cannot figure out the requirements or that someone just maliciously downvotes us.

Comment: recived a error : cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Array'