# How to Copy, filter and sort a list in just one statement in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of objects. I want to temporarily create second list out of some objects in the original list and sort the second list. After I am done using the second list, I want to discard this list but still keep the original list

How do I do this in an elegant manner?

Please use below as eg:

```
public class Person
{
    public int index {get; set;}
    public int score {get; set;}
};
```

I have a list defined like this;

```
List<Person>  myList;
```

`myList` is originally sorted based on `index`. I want a *temporary list* created out of `myList` for `scores` between `50` and `75`, sorted based on `score`.

Update: This question is marked as a possible duplicate of another question (which answers how to sort), but I need more than sorting
a) coping the list 
b) filtering out elements 
c) sort it

Comment: [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](//stackoverflow.com/a/3309230)

Comment: What is 'LINQ'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using LINQ:

```
myList.Where(p => p.score >= 50 && p.score <= 70).OrderByDescending(p => p.score).ToList();
```

This will give you a new list with persons that have score between 50 and 70 and will sort it (bigger person with score is first).

Answer (score 2):

Querying is the thing *Linq* has been designed for:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 List<Person> myTempList = myList
   .Where(item => item.score > 50 && item.score < 75)
   .OrderBy(item => item.score)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

using `LINQ`:

```
var newList  = myList.Where(s=>s.score>=50 && s.score<=75).OrderBy(s=>s.score).ToList();
```