# Sorting a List<List<T>>

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to sort a `List<List<T>>` say `#myList`. `T` has the properties `QuestionName` and `Response`.

I need to sort the `#mylist` based on response to a particular question. Here's my code:

```
public class T
{
    public string QuestionName {get; set;}
    public string Response {get; set;}
}

List<List<T>> myList = new List<List<T>>();

List<T> tList = new List<T>();    
tList.add({QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "BBB"});
tList.add({QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "BBBLastName"});
myList.add(tList);

tList = new List<T>();
tList.add({QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "AAA"});
tList.add({QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "AAACLastName"});
myList.add(tList);

tList = new List<T>();
tList.add({QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "CCC"});
tList.add({QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "CCCLastName"});
myList.add(tList);
```

This basically corresponds to a table - where each `T` is a cell, `List<T>` is a row and `List<List<T>>` is the table.

I need to sort rows of the table (`List<T>`) based on the response to the FirstName question.

I searched web, but did not find a single post about sorting `List<List<T>>`. Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: Use Linq's OrderBy extension function

Comment: That post talks about sorting a list  , I am trying to sort a list of list

Comment: I can use orderby if it is a list<T> , may be myList.orderby(x => x.property), but I need to sort a list of list

Comment: Nothing in your code can be compiled, please post a code which can be compiled

Comment: I am not very clear about your exact requirement, but what you can do for `List<List<T>>` is `myList.OrderBy(list => list.First())`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: OrderBy works with any List<T>, even if T = List<T2>.

Comment: Your code, as is, does not compile. It may be easier for us if it did compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the working version of what you expect:

```
class T
{
    public string QuestionName { get; set;}

    public string Response { get; set;}
 }


void Main()
{
    List<List<T>> myList = new List<List<T>>();

    List<T> tList = new List<T>();
    tList.Add(new T { QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "BBB"});
    tList.Add(new T{ QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "BBBLastName"});
    myList.Add(tList.OrderBy(x => x.Response).ToList());

    List<T> tList1 = new List<T>();
    tList1.Add(new T{ QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "AAA"});
    tList1.Add(new T{ QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "AAACLastName"});
    myList.Add(tList1.OrderBy(x => x.Response).ToList());

    List<T> tList2 = new List<T>();
    tList2.Add(new T{ QuestionName = "FirstName", Response = "CCC"});
    tList2.Add(new T{ QuestionName = "LastName", Response = "CCCLastName"});
    myList.Add(tList2.OrderBy(x => x.Response).ToList());

    myList =
    myList.OrderBy(list => list.First().Response).ToList();
}
```

---

### How it Works:

1. Each `Row` or sub list is ordered and arranged using the `Response` property
2. For `List<List<T>`, we use the `list.First().Response` for ordering.
3. Print is created using `LinqPad - Dump` API, you may though some other convenient API

### Following is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mrinal, I will make sure to include a working version of code from next time

Comment: I assume this satisfies your expected use case

Comment: Thanks for the information Mrinal, I tried myList.OrderBy(list => list.First().Response) and that doesn't seem to be working for me. I also tried  myList.OrderBy(x => x.Find(y => y.QuestionName.ToLower().Contains("firstname")).Response).  I am I doing something wrong? Sorry for my lack of understanding

Comment: @Sri I have provided working code to you, please check what in this code doesn't meet your expectation, The result is what I have posted, is that the expected result ?

Comment: that is the expected result and I am able to get it to work, it was helpful - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer - Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhDSTk)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public  void Main()
    {
        List<List<ABC>> myList = new List<List<ABC>>();

        List<ABC> tList = new List<ABC>();    
        tList.Add(new ABC(){QuestionName = "EFirstName", Response = "BBB"});
        tList.Add(new ABC(){QuestionName = "BLastName", Response = "BBBLastName"});
        myList.Add(tList);

        List<ABC> bList = new List<ABC>();    
        tList.Add(new ABC(){QuestionName = "zFirstName", Response = "BBB"});
        tList.Add(new ABC(){QuestionName = "QLastName", Response = "BBBLastName"});
        myList.Add(bList);

        Console.WriteLine("Normal List");

        foreach(var item in myList){
            foreach(var innerItem in item){
                  Console.WriteLine(innerItem.QuestionName + " | "+innerItem.Response);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        // Sort
        var sortedList = myList.Select(x=>x.OrderBy(y=> y.QuestionName)).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine("Sorted List");
        foreach(var item in sortedList){
            foreach(var innerItem in item){
                 Console.WriteLine(innerItem.QuestionName + " | "+innerItem.Response);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the example does not come close to compiling, I rearranged a few things and went with a List of Dictionary.

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> questions = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
questions.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
    { "FirstName", "BBB" },
    { "LastName", "BBBLastName" }
});
questions.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
    { "FirstName", "AAA" },
    { "LastName", "AAACLastName" }
});
questions.Add(new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
    { "FirstName", "CCC" },
    { "LastName", "CCCLastName" }
});

questions.Sort((a,b) => {
    List<string> tmp = new List<string>() { a["FirstName"], b["FirstName"] };
    tmp.Sort();
    return !a["FirstName"].Equals(tmp[0]) ? 1 : -1;
});

questions.ForEach(x => {
    x.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, x[key]));
});
```