# How to sort List<T> in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I've got a `List<Card>`, and I want to sort these cards

So, I'm looking for a method to sort them with different criterias, like their `ID`, their `Name` ...

```
public class Card : IComparer
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
    public int CompareId(object firstCard, object secondCard) 
    {
        Card c1 = (Card)firstCard;
        Card c2 = (Card)secondCard;
        return c1.Id.CompareTo(c2.Id);
    }
}
```

But then, visual studio sent me an error :

> `'Card'` does not implement interface member `'IComparer<Card>.Compare(Card, Card)'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You, probably, want to have your class [*Comparable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) not a [*Comparator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer)

```
public class Card : IComparable<Card>
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;

    public int CompareTo(Card other) 
    {
        if (null == other)
            return 1;

        // string.Compare is safe when Id is null 
        return string.Compare(this.Id, other.Id);
    }
}
```

then

```
List<Card> myList = ...

myList.Sort();
```

**Edit:** If you want to have *several* criteria to choose from, you have to implement several Comparers as separated classes, e.g.

```
public sealed class CardByIdComparer : IComparer<Card> 
{
    public int Compare(Card x, Card y) 
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
        else if (null == x)
            return -1;
        else if (null == y)
            return 1;
        else
            return string.Compare(x.Id, y.Id);
    }
}
```

and when sorting provide the required:

```
List<Card> myList = ...

myList.Sort(new CardByIdComparer());
```

**Edit 2:** (inspired by spender's library). If you want to *combine* several comparers into one (i.e. use `comparer1`, on tie - `comparer2` etc.)

```
public sealed class ComparerCombined<T> : IComparer<T> {
  private IComparer<T>[] m_Comparers;

  public ComparerCombined(params IComparer<T>[] comparers) {
    if (null == comparers)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparers));

    m_Comparers = comparers
      .Select(item => item == null ? Comparer<T>.Default : item)
      .Where(item => item != null)
      .Distinct()
      .ToArray();
  }

  public int Compare(T x, T y) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return 0;
    else if (null == x)
      return -1;
    else if (null == y)
      return 1;

    foreach (var comparer in m_Comparers) {
      int result = comparer.Compare(x, y);

      if (result != 0)
        return result;
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
myList.Sort(new ComparerCombined(
  new CardByIdComparer(),   // Sort By Id
  new CardByNameComparer()  // On tie (equal Id's) sort by name
));
```

Comment: I wrote a library to help with multiple comparison criteria: https://github.com/biggyspender/ComparerBuilder ... however, given that LINQ handles this so gracefully, its absence from this answer is, to me, conspicuous.

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way You can use Linq:

```c#
List<Card> objSortedList = objListObject.OrderBy(o=>o.ID).ToList();
```

or

```c#
List<Card> objSortedList = objListObject.OrderByDescending(o=>o.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: but probably not using `OrderByColumnName` but rather e.g. `ID`

Answer (score 1):

[Good examples for](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-list-in-c-sharp-set-1/) demonstrate the concept of
`List<T>.Sort(IComparer <T>)` method  check the link please.

`IComparer<T>` in this example compare method used for strings `IComparer<T>`
but you can use this for ID(int) too.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 

class GFG : IComparer<string> 
{ 
    public int Compare(string x, string y) 
    { 
        if (x == null || y == null) 
        { 
            return 0; 
        } 

        // "CompareTo()" method 
        return x.CompareTo(y); 

    } 
} 



public class geek 
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>(); 

        // list elements 
        list1.Add("C++"); 
        list1.Add("Java"); 
        list1.Add("C"); 
        list1.Add("Python"); 
        list1.Add("HTML"); 
        list1.Add("CSS"); 
        list1.Add("Scala"); 
        list1.Add("Ruby"); 
        list1.Add("Perl"); 

        int range = 4; 

        GFG gg = new GFG(); 

        Console.WriteLine("\nSort a range with comparer:"); 

        // sort the list within a  
        // range of index 1 to 4 
        // where range = 4 
        list1.Sort(1, range, gg); 

        Console.WriteLine("\nBinarySearch and Insert Dart"); 

        // Binary Search and storing  
        // index value to "index" 
        int index = list1.BinarySearch(0, range, 
                                    "Dart", gg); 

        if (index < 0) 
        { 
            list1.Insert(~index, "Dart"); 
            range++; 
        } 

    } 


}
```

Comment: Don't post only a link. Rather reproduce a complete answer here and explain how the described method works in the questions case

Comment: @derHugo thank you for reply I will be careful next time

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement IComparer

```
public int Compare(Card card1, Card card2)
{
   if (card1.ID > card2.ID)
      return 1; //move card1 up
   if (card2.ID  < card1.ID)
      return -1; //move card2 up
  return 0; //do nothing
}
```

Comment: How is this different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371490/7111561) answer?

Comment: It's not different, I wrote it on my own, the problem is simple and we came up with the same implementation

Comment: well with a twelve minute delay but ok ;)

Comment: I'm not the fastest, but still navigating through the beautiful world of C#