# how to sort models by specific property and show it to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

i have model class called SCARF and it has ID,title,name,price property 
the name property is unique for every SCARF but title dont
i have plenty SCARf with same title
i want to sort SCARF by title and show it to view by title

Comment: Sorting implies a collection, like `List<SCARF>` so you can use LINQ in your controller (or view) to sort: `var sortedList = unsortedList.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();` Then in your view use a `foreach` with table rows to display the data.

Comment: please check this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371579/6923146

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a collection of `SCARF` class, `List<SCARF>`. you just need to call `OrderBy` method of `List`.

```
var sortedList = scarfsList.OrderBy(s => s.Title).ToList();
```