# How to sort a list C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I've got a class called "Order" that has a 
"Order Number"  and a "Weight".

I've got a list of orders that is unorganized.
I'd like to sort this List by the weight of each order. Ascending and Descending.

```
        {
            return new List<Order>() {
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =1,
             Weight = 1.2
            },
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =2,
             Weight = 1.2
            },
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =3,
             Weight = 1.2
            },
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =4,
             Weight = 2
            },
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =5,
             Weight = 1.2
            },
             new Order(){
             OrderNumber =6,
             Weight = 1.2
            }
            };
        }
```

I would want to create a List OrganizedOrders in which the heaviest (Order Number 4) would be at the top of this list.

Thank you a lot. I know this is very basic but i'm just getting started.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luciano try using a lambda expression. Where your list is called myOrders:

```
myOrders.OrderBy(o => o.Weight);
```

Or for descending:

```
myOrders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Weight);
```

Either of which you could save into a new list if you really need to:

```
List<Order> ascendingOrders = myOrders.OrderBy(o => o.Weight).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked before ([How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object))

Use LINQ:

```
List<Order> SortedList = myOrderList.OrderBy(o=>o.Weight).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Order> SortedList = myOrderList.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Weight).ToList();
```

Comment: Please flag duplicates instead of creating duplicate answers, especially when you found the duplicate already.

Comment: Agreed! If you know it's a duplicate you can click the `close` link, choose `Duplicate of...` and then paste in the link to the dup.