# C# how to extract values from for-loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, return

I am new to programming and got stuck on an assignment.

The assignment is to input name, age and number of sales for 4 different workers. After that I need to post the workers in order based on their amount of sales.

Where I am mostly stuck is the loop-part. I do not understand how I can insert values to the 4 workers and then return their values in order.

```
        int pay = 1000;

            Console.WriteLine("What is the first- and lastname of the worker: ");
            string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What is the age of the worker: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What district does the worker work at: ");
            string district = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("How many sales has the worker done: ");
            int sales = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Name\t\tAge\tDistrict\tSales");
        Console.WriteLine(name + "\t" + age + "\t" + district + "\t\t" + sales);

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        if (sales > 199)
        {
            pay = pay + sales * 4;
            Console.WriteLine(name + " is level 4 \nand will get: " + pay + "kr this month");
        }
        else if (sales <= 199 && sales >= 100)
        {
            pay = pay + sales * 3;
            Console.WriteLine(name + " is level 3 \nand will get: " + pay + "kr this month");
        }
        else if (sales <= 99 && sales >= 50)
        {
            pay = pay + sales * 2;
            Console.WriteLine(name + " is level 2 \nand will get: " + pay + "kr this month");
        }
        else
        {
            pay = pay + sales;
            Console.WriteLine(name + " is level 1\nand will get: " + pay + "kr this month");
        }
```

~
Please excuse the mess, I have yet to learn the proper structure of coding.

Comment: Please share the code that you have already wrote, it's important to share your efforts with the community so we can help you better, edit your question and add the code you have written, regardless if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Worker class will hold information about one worker:

```
public class Worker() 
{
    string Name;
    int NumberOfSales;
    int Age;

    public Worker(string _n, int _nos, int _a) 
    {
        Name = _n;
        NumberOfSales = _nos;
        Age = _a;
    }
}
```

This piece of code will run for 4 times, get information about workers, create Worker object for everyone of them and then add the objects to `Workers` List object:

```
List<Worker> Workers = new List<Workers>();
int Worker = 1;
for (int i = Worker; i < 5; i++)  
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter name for Worker {0}", Worker);
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter age for Worker {0}", Worker);
    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of sales for Worker {0}", Worker);
    nOfSales = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Worker worker = new Worker(name, age, nOfSales);
    Workers.Add(worker);
}
```

In this following link, you can learn how to sort your `Workers` list object, by looking at every `Worker` object's `NumberOfSales` property: [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)