# Order by multiple lists of object

Tags: c#, linq

I've three lists in an object and want to perform order by operation using LINQ

**object containing lists**

```
public class ApplicationCommunications
{
    public ApplicationCommunications()
    {
        listNotification = new List<ApplicationNotifications>();
        listEmail = new List<ApplicationEmail>();
        listSMS = new List<ApplicationSMS>();
    }

    public List<ApplicationNotifications> listNotification { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationEmail> listEmail { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationSMS> listSMS { get; set; }
}
```

**Getting data from db**

```
ApplicationCommunications applicationCommunications = new ApplicationCommunications();
applicationCommunications.listNotification = GetApplicationNotification(applicationId).Select(c => new ApplicationNotifications
{
    NotificationId =  c.NotificationId,
    Message = c.Message,
    SendDate = c.SendDate.Value
}).ToList();

applicationCommunications.listEmail = GetApplicationEmails(applicationId).Select(t => new ApplicationEmail
{
    EmailContent = t.Body,
    EmailAddress = t.Email,
    SendDate = t.SendDate.Value,
}).ToList();

applicationCommunications.listSMS = GetApplicationMessage(applicationId).Select(t => new ApplicationSMS
{
    SMSContent = t.Body,
    PhoneNumber = t.Phone,
    SendDate = t.SendDate.Value,
}).ToList();
```

We've three lists each list of the object has "senddate" property now I want to make a new list from these three lists where we will have data in order. Is that possible?

How we can perform order by with send date? simply I want to display data in order.

Comment: Do you see that ordering three lists is different than just ordering one? If not, you might simplify your question to come closer to the core of what you want to discover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: Yes, you are right I want to order by each send date property. simply I want to display data in order. @Dejan

Comment: @user12577393: _what_ you want to order? A single list, all three lists or something that contains instances of this `ApplicationCommunications`-class?

Comment: @TimSchmelter pardon for the incomplete question. We've three lists each list of the object has "senddate" property now I want to make a new list from these three lists where we will have data in order. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pardon for the incomplete question. We've three lists each list of the
> object has "senddate" property now I want to make a new list from
> these three lists where we will have data in order. Is that possible?

As shown in the other answer you need `OrderBy`:

```
List<DateTime> orderedSendDates = applicationCommunications.listNotification
    .Select(x => x.NotificationSendDate)
    .Concat(applicationCommunications.listEmail.Select(x => x.EmailSendDate))
    .Concat(applicationCommunications.listSMS.Select(x => x.SMSSendDate))
    .OrderBy(dt => dt)
    .ToList();
```

If you want unique `DateTime`s use `Distinct` before the `OrderBy`.

If you don't have these properties initialized when you want the list you could do:

```
List<DateTime> orderedSendDates = 
    GetApplicationNotification(applicationId).Select(x => x.SendDate)
    .Concat(GetApplicationEmails(applicationId).Select(x => x.SendDate))
    .Concat(GetApplicationMessage(applicationId).Select(x => x.SendDate))
    .Where(sendDateOrNull => sendDateOrNull.HasValue)
    .Select(sendDateOrNull => sendDateOrNull.Value)
    .OrderBy(dt => dt)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to do.

Comment: So you get just a list of `DateTime`. How would you add some data (description, Id) to your list elements so that you retrieve the real Email, Notifications, Sms objects ?

Comment: @XouDo: OP is just interested in the `SendDate` property which is a `Nullable<DateTime>` and he wants an ordered `List<DateTime>` of it. He wasn't clear in his requirement. Of course you lose the relation to the other information.

Answer (score 3):

`Select` method gives you `Enumerable` type of list. `Enumerable` can be ordered by `OrderBy`, so simply do this

```
applicationCommunications.listNotification = GetApplicationNotification(applicationId).Select(c => new ApplicationNotifications
        {
            NotificationId =  c.NotificationId,
            Message = c.Message,
            NotificationSendDate = c.SendDate.Value
        })
        .OrderBy(an => an.NotificationSendDate)
        .ThenBy(an => an.NotificationId)
        .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
You can read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0

Comment: This will only order by listNotifications. is there any way we can compare with other lists?

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably don't get it quite well what you try to achieve. Every list of yours have different parameters which makes impossible to compare every list with each other. You can order every list like I did with listNotification and then you would have 3 lists ordered as you wanted. If this doesn't help, could you please provide example of data how would you like to have lists ordered?

Comment: pardon for the incomplete question. We've three lists each list of the object has "senddate" property now I want to make a new list from these three lists where we will have data in order. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a big list containing the different types of elements, ordered by sendDate (but not just a list of dateTime), you may first create a common type for that :

```
    public class SentElement {
        public string ElementDescription {get ; set;}
        public DateTime SendDate { get; set;}
    }
```

Then map your different types to the common type using `Select`, filling the description the way you want for each type of element:

```
var listNotification = GetApplicationNotification(applicationId).Select(c => new SentElement
{
    ElementDescription = c.NotificationId + c.Message,
    SendDate= c.SendDate.Value
}).ToList();
    
var listEmail = GetApplicationEmails(applicationId).Select(t =>  new SentElement
{
    ElementDescription = t.EmailContent + t.EmailAddress,
    SendDate = t.SendDate.Value,
}).ToList();
    
var listSMS = GetApplicationMessage(applicationId).Select(t => new SentElement
{
    ElementDescription = t.Body + t.Phone,
    SendDate = t.SendDate.Value,
}).ToList();
```

And finally merging and ordering the result :

```
  var mergedList = listNotification.Concat(listEmail).Concat(listSMS).OrderByDescending(t=> t.SendDate);
```