# How to fetch the listview data from the mobile local DB in an ascending order?

Tags: sqlite, maui

In my project, I'm saving the data from the API call to the mobile database using SQLite. I want to fetch the listview data from the mobile database based on a date and time in ascending order.

Date format: 2024-01-03

Time format: 09:48:11

Below is the code for fetching the data from the mobile database on the SqlHelper class:

```
public List<MessageLog> GetMessageLogs()
{
lock (locker)
{
    return database.Table<MessageLog>().ToList();
}
}
```

Can you please provide a solution for fetching the listview data from the mobile database in ascending order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: I referred to the given Stack Overflow link and tried to fetch the listview data based on the date and time in ascending order. But, based on the date's first digit, the listview data are getting fetched. I have updated the question with the date and time format.

Comment: Are you storing date and time as **strings**?  If so, that is a very bad practice exactly because it causes these types of issues.

Comment: We are saving the data from the API call to our mobile local db. I want to fetch the data from our mobile local db based on the date and time. We are storing the date and time as strings. Is there any way to fetch the data from our mobile local db based on the date and time?

Comment: Your question is about sorting the data, not fetching it.  Both would be much, much easier if you used the proper datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to save the dateandtime using a `DateTime` datatype to local DB

```
public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
```

Then use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` as per your needs.

```
public List<MessageLog> GetMessageLogsByDateTime()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return database.Table<MessageLog>().OrderByDescending(x => x.dateTime).ToList();
    }
}
```